# Angular Material Tabs - Load/Unload components only when active tab is selected

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

Given the following code of MainComponent.html:

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="onTabClick($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Users">
    <!-- Active Tab. This tab is shown first -->
    <app-users></app-users>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Managers">
    <app-managers></app-managers>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

There are two components that are **both** loaded and ran when this view is called. i.e. the ngOnInit for the ManagersComponent (the inactive tab) is called.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-managers',
    templateUrl: './managers.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./managers.component.scss']
})
export class ManagersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
      //This is called when the MainComponent is loaded. 
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {

    }
}
```

Is there a way to load and destroy components so that only the active tab is loaded, and the inactive tabs don't load until they are clicked, and destroyed when left?

i.e. in the code snippet above the ngOnInit won't be loaded for ManagersComponent until the active tab is selected and when left the ngOnDestroy will be called

Answer (score 31):

you can use `<ng-template>` with the `matTabContent` attribute in the `<mat-tab>`

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="onTabClick($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Users">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-users></app-users>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Managers">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-managers></app-managers>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[see documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading)

Comment: I don't believe this will completely fulfill the OP's requirement. The OP also required that the component be destroyed when navigating away from the tab. This will only lazy load the component when the tab is activated, but not destroy it when navigating away.

Comment: @Narm Correct, I want the ngOnDestroy to be called when the tab is navigated away from

Comment: The only way I know of at current state is to use the `ngIf` directive which will create and destroy the components or use dynamic components and manually control the process which is way too heavy and unnecessary solution for this requirement

Comment: You can maybe destroy it manually ` @ViewChild(ChildCmp)
    childCmp: ChildCmp;
    destroyChildClick(){
        this.childCmp.destroy();
    }`

Comment: This seems to work. Based from my testing, it looks like that the component inside the mat-tab gets destroyed when it's not active.

Comment: what a perfect answer for my situation, thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `*ngIf` directive **so that the components only gets loaded when the active tab is selected and then destroyed when it becomes inactive.** An example would be something like:

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="onTabClick($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Users">
    <!-- Active Tab. This tab is shown first -->
    <app-users *ngIf="!managerActive"></app-users>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Managers">
    <app-managers *ngIf="managerActive"></app-managers>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

From the [Angular Material mat-tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api) documentation it looks like there is an `isActive` property you could use as the flag which would probably be the ideal way.

Comment: Correct answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634256/5350404

Comment: @batbrain9392 you would be surprised, but _narm_ have a correct answer to the question. `matTabContent` indeed makes tabs lazy-loaded instead of eagerly-loaded, but `matTabContent` doesn't destroy previous component immediately after changing of tabs that leads to 2 components presence in DOM simultaneously. This approach has a `~30ms` faster destruction of previous component in compare with _adrien-pessu_ answer and they substitute one another. As conclusion, without `matTabContent` and with *ngIf will make truly lazy-loaded components.

Answer (score 4):

Just completing the example for the `isActive` mechanism that @Narm alludes to. Put a reference label on each matTab and then you can use its `isActive` property immediately to manually create/destroy each tab's content.

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="onTabClick($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Users" #users>
    <!-- Active Tab. This tab is shown first -->
    <app-users *ngIf="users.isActive"></app-users>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Managers" #managers>
    <app-managers *ngIf="managers.isActive"></app-managers>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I just solved my problem with this solution. It worked like a charm to ensure that only one component is alive at a time. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

use

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="onTabClick($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Users">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-users *ngIf="!managerActive"></app-users>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Managers">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
       <app-managers *ngIf="managerActive"></app-managers>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Due to poor documentation of Angular Material, it was hard to find. 
But ng-template enables lazyloading for tabs.
`<ng-template matTabContent></ng-template>`